# Spring Boot - JDBC connection problems on external tomcat server

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I have created a spring boot application that I deploy as a WAR file on an external Tomcat server.

Everything works fine when I use application.properties as follow to define my database connection:

```
#spring.datasource.platform=mysql
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://a.b.c.d/dbname
#spring.datasource.username=user
#spring.datasource.password=password
```

However, when I try to manage the connection from the Tomcat server instead of application properties, I get the following error :

> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

## application.properties

```
spring.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=15 
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000 
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50 
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=15 
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=8 
spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit=true 
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=false
```

## pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-batch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/jquery -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/jquery-ui -->



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.el/javax.el-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1-b06</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-csv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generatePackage>com.lasalle.soldierssoap</generatePackage>
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>


    </build>

</project>
```

## Tomcat - Context.xml

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/testDB"
                global="jdbc/testDB"
                auth="Container"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

## Tomcat - Server.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MyDB" 
      global="jdbc/testDB" 
      auth="Container" 
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
      url="jdbc:mysql://a.b.c.d:3306/dbname" 
      username="user" 
      password="password" 
      maxActive="100" 
      maxIdle="20" 
      minIdle="5" 
      maxWait="10000"/>
```

I have also copied mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar to tomcat/lib.

Comment: If you want tomcat to handle your datasource, then your app shouldn't have tomcat-jdbc as a deendency, and shoudn't try to configure the connection pool, since it's precisely not managed by the app, but by Tomcat. Red https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connecting-to-a-jndi-datasource for how to get a JNDI DataSource (which is how you obtain it from Tomcat, as explained here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources

Answer (score -1):

In your **application.property** file add these.

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false
jdbc.user=root
jdbc.pass=1234

# hibernate.X
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
```

OR

```
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schoolmgt?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

hope these are working for you.

Comment: This would have the app handling the data source.  That is not what I am trying to achieve.  I am trying to handle the database connection through the Tomcat server configuration.